# Microsoft Entra Password Hash Synchronization vs Microsoft Entra pass-through authentication

Tags: microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

What is the difference between Microsoft Entra Password Hash Synchronization and Microsoft Entra pass-through authentication.

As per this link: both looks same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-pta